# How do I run this to perform a FAST greenplum health check?

Tags: greenplum

I  have downloaded this script from gitub:  https://github.com/rjw41x/greenplum-healthcheck
Never used it before, but I need to NOW.  Below is the 'usage' from the readme.  I have creaed my own gp_health directory and extracted the sh files from the health_scripts.tgz into that directory, but don't know where to go from here.  I attempted to run auto_health.sh from the command line, but it just tells me Windows cannot open that kind of file.  Can anybody tell me how to call the scripts against the GP instance?

mkdir gp_health
tar xzf health_scripts.tgz -C gp_health
cd gp_health
./auto_health.sh

Comment: Maybe a better question would simply be how do I run shell scripts on Windows?  Is the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) feature and a reboot all that is needed?  Does anyone have any information to provide regarding this or the GP health check?

Comment: I did WSL but receied the error below when attempting to then run the shell schripts thereafter.  CAN ANYBODY HELP WITH THIS?


C:\Windows\system32>wsl.exe /install
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore